# Accounting for different factors during construction of hypotheses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normalization, standardization, z-test

I am a beginner in statistics (we are using statistics in a Data Science introduction course)

We are learning about hypothesis testing and we have been asked to write Python code to perform hypothesis testing on any column of a given dataset. My dataset consists of 592 places (which would be the rows) and I want to perform hypothesis testing on one of the columns containing values of the literacy rate in those 592 places.

I want to compare the mean of the current year's literacy rate with the previous years. According to the internet, the literacy rate for the previous year is 58.6%.

I have normalized and standardized the values in the Literacy Rate column.

I want my hypotheses to be:
   $\qquad H_0: μ_X \geq 58.6$
   $\qquad H_1: μ_Y < 58.6$

I want to use z-test to test this hypothesis.

Now I have a few doubts:

1. Should I take a sample out of the 592 values? And obtain mean and standard deviation of that sample to use in my z test?
2. Since my values have been normalized and standardized, the values in my column have been re-scaled. Now according to my textbook, we need the mean and standard deviation to obtain the z score which in turn is used to obtain p-value.

To obtain the z score I will be using the following formula:
  $\qquad z = (X−56.8)/\text{Std Dev}$

But it seems wrong to subtract it with a value like 56.8 while my mean values might be different due to the normalization and standardization. Should I actually use normalized and standardized values to perform a Hypothesis Test?

3. The above question leads to another doubt. Am I using the value 58.6 in the right manner?

My thought process seems fine to me, based on the examples given in my textbook. But please tell me what is off about this testing. I am relatively new to this and they have tried to stuff a lot into a 4 month course which has made further exploration of the topic quite difficult. I understand if it sounds like a basic question or that I haven't done my research but most of the websites talk about the decision making part rather than the construction of the hypotheses itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are estimating the variance from the sample, then technically you should use one-sided t-test. Z-test is for known variance and its sufficient statistic (the z) is distributed according to the normal distribution, whereas t-statistic is distributed according to Student t-distribution. However in practice, for a sample of 592, t-distribution is hardly distinguishable from the normal one.

So the answer to your question 1: Use all the 592 values, calculating the mean and the standard deviation from the sample, and use t-test. You use all values because you are merely testing: there is no training and testing a model, so there is no need to divide your sample in two or three datasets.

Regarding your questions 2 and 3: if any standardization and/or normalization are involved, they should be the same for your dataset and for the dataset used to obtain value $58.6$. In practice, I am not sure there will be much difference: you could run t-test twice.

Comment: Our textbook said any sample above size 30 should use z test, so I thought that was the way to go about it. But maybe comparing with a typical data-set, 592 rows are less in number. I obtained the value 58.6 from the internet, I have no idea about what sort of dataset they used to obtain this answer. I may run the test twice

Comment: As I have already mentioned, t-distribution is very similar to normal for large samples, this is what the textbook seems to suggest. I agree that trying twice is a better option here.